# (WPF) How to set value of a sys:Double to SystemFonts.MessageFontSize from ResourceDictionary?

Tags: wpf, font-size, resourcedictionary, dynamicresource

**Scenario:**

I want to use 3 standard font size for my WPF application : `BigFontSize`, `NormalFontSize`, and `SmallFontSize`. These are double values and they are defined in resource dictionary as (where `sys` is appropriately defined):

```
<sys:Double x:Key="BigFontSize">18</sys:Double>
<sys:Double x:Key="NormalFontSize">14</sys:Double>
<sys:Double x:Key="SmallFontSize">12</sys:Double>
```

This works well. But i have randomly selected 14 as a normal size. What i want is to get a system defined font size for `NormalFontSize`. (If that's done, I can use a converter [as described **here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311734/wpf-custom-control-template-relative-font-size/311774#311774) to get `BigFontSize` and `SmallFontSize` relative to `NormalFontSize`)

**Clue :**

I found from the documentation that default font size is stored in a static property (double) `SystemFonts.MessageFontSize`. But what should I do to retrieve that value to resource dictionary? (I know `Binding` or `DynamicResource` cannot be applied. But hey, this is a static value, so how can I apply `StaticResource` or `x:Static` or whatever?)

I have tried

```
<sys:Double x:Key="XXXFontSize">
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="SystemFonts.MessageFontSize" />
</sys:Double>
```

and

```
<sys:Double x:Key="XXXFontSize">
    <x:Static ResourceKey="SystemFonts.MessageFontSize" />
</sys:Double>
```

Both of which doesn't seem to work (as expected). I get an error saying `Cannot add content to object of type 'System.Double'.`

**Note:**

- I don't want to do this from code, e.g from App(). (Is it possible to have a code-behind for ResourceDictionary?)
- I don't want to encapsulate this in generalized style from which other styles can be derived (using `BasedOn`) because I have several Resource Dictionaries, and it'll not be possible to use `DynamicResource` with `BasedOn`
  That is, I cannot use

  ```
  <Style x:Key="BigFont" TargetType="{x:Type Control}"}>
      <Setter Property="Control.FontSize" 
              Value="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemFonts.MessageFontSize},
                              Converter={ . . . }" />
  </Style>
  ```

  Because, if I have a style in other ResourceDictionary, say `HeaderTextBlockStyle`, then I would have to use `BasedOn={DynamicResource BigFont}` which is not possible (I think)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

**TAGS** : WPF SystemFonts.MessageFontSize ResourceDictionary FontSize BasedOn DynamicResource

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done like this...

```
public partial class GlobalResources : ResourceDictionary
{
    public GlobalResources()
    {
        this.Add("GiantFontSize", SystemFonts.MessageFontSize * 2.5);
        this.Add("BigFontSize", SystemFonts.MessageFontSize * 1.5);
        this.Add("MediumFontSize", SystemFonts.MessageFontSize * 1.25);
        this.Add("NormalFontSize", SystemFonts.MessageFontSize);
        this.Add("SmallFontSize", SystemFonts.MessageFontSize * 0.85);
    }
}
```

... and it's working like like a miracle!!! I can use these resources in the same (partial) resource dictionary or from other resource dictionaries like this...

```
<Style ...>
    <Setter Property="FontSize"
            Value="{DynamicResource MediumFontSize}" />

    ...

</Style>
```

I don't know if it is a "good practice" or not (please comment on this), I only know that it works..!!!